# PHP regex...getting first instance of end bracket?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, bbcode

Hi i am trying to parse some homemade bbcode i came up with and having a difficult time with something. I am new to regex but thought this would be a great way to teach myself.

**[%url=http://google.com]google link[/url%]**

```
<a href='google.com' google link </a>
```

**[%video=http://youtube.com?v=blah]**

```
i will run the link through a automatic embed function 
developed in php..i just need to parse the link
```

**[%PAGEBREAK%]**

```
<hr>
```

**[%img=wateva.jpg%]**

```
<img src='wateva.jpg'>
```

So far I have done the url one which worked great...see below

```
$url_pattern = "/\[\s*%\s*(URL|url)\s*=\s*(.*)\](.*)\[\s*\/\s*(URL|url)\s*%\s*\]/i";
$description = preg_replace($url_pattern, "<a href='$2'>$3</a>", $description);
```

But when i tried to do the image...(see below)

```
$img_pattern ="/\[\s*%\s*(IMG|img)=(.*)\s*(%\s*\])/i";
$description = preg_replace($img_pattern, "<img src=\'$2\' style='width: 700px; height: auto; display:block;\'>", $description);
```

### It picks up the last "%]" of the whole text instead of the closest "%]"..how do i tell it to find the closest %]?

**Here is my testing TEXT:**

*100 word minimum. Give a description of your project combined with images, video, and or links.. just don't write a novel! Use images that correspond with your text by using the images section below. The icons in the description bar will allow you to add other media like links and videos.100 word minimum. Give a description of your project combined with images, video, and or links.. just don't write a novel! Use images that correspond with your text by using the images section below. The icons in the description bar will allow you to add other media like links and videos.100 word minimum. Give a description of your project combined with images, video, and or links..

[%PAGEBREAK%]

[%IMG=uploads/06-26-11/Cog.gif%]

just don't write a novel! Use images that correspond with your text by using the images section below. The icons in the description bar will allow you to add other media like links and videos.100 word minimum. Give a description of your project combined with images, video, and or links.. just don't write a novel! Use images that correspond with your text by using the images section below. The icons in the description bar will allow you to add other media like links and videos.

This is a [%URL=http://google.com]link[/URL%]

Here is a video by gang gang dance

[%VIDEO=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZMFwKVjV5s%]*

Comment: BB-code implementation is often a FSM, not a set of regular expressions.

Comment: As a side note, my favorite regex site - perfect for playing around with complex expressions until you get it just right: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Your regex seems fine. Am I missing something? http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=7aa29bfd-999f-40b3-a26c-98014e436341

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely `.*` in `/\[\s*%\s*(IMG|img)=(.*)\s*(%\s*\])/i`. `*` is greedy - it will match to the end of the document, and then backtrack to the *last* `%]` to match it. Normally, the problem would be hidden unless you've set the `/s` flag, which causes `.` to match newlines (and also called the `Dot-All` flag).
A simple solution is to use a lazy quantifier, so `.*?` matches nothing by default, but then machtrack to match more and more character until it finds the *first* `%]`:

```
/\[\s*%\s*(img)=(.*?)\s*(%\s*\])/i
```

A better option is to define what alphabet is acceptable in `img` tags. For example, anything other than a `]` or a newline:

```
/\[\s*%\s*(img)=([^\]\n\r]*)\s*(%\s*\])/i
```

See also: [Laziness Instead of Greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy)

You probably want to fix the other patterns as well, they share the same problem.
Finally, I'd advice to look at an implementation of an existing bbcode parser. These codes can have nested constructs (for example, an image in a link in a blockquote), making them tricky to parse correctly.